# How to get parent element of my element?

Tags: python, lxml

For example:

```
test = label.find('image').attrib['url']
```

How to get parent element of image ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `getparent()` method:

```
image_parent = label.find('image').getparent()
```